# Как на golang просмотреть список дисков и флешек, подключенных к компьютеру?

Tags: golang

Как на golang просмотреть список дисков и флешек, подключенных к компьютеру?

Comment: Думаю очень сильно от ОС будет зависеть.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux

Comment: ну если Windows

Comment: windows http://superuser.com/questions/139899/see-available-drives-from-windows-cli

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в любой язык подобный функционал встроен. Думаю надо с ос инструментарием работать или искать библиотеку которая это обернет.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128148/how-can-i-get-a-listing-of-all-drives-on-windows-using-golang

Comment: а как это прицепить к golang?

Comment: [Вот тут ответ есть о том как из golang получить доступ к драйву если это windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128148/how-can-i-get-a-listing-of-all-drives-on-windows-using-golang)